# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined when making my discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i am having having a problem with this code here is code:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "amstronglikeabullinapool")) {
    message.channel.send("ok i dont care")
    const user = message.member;

    var guild = client.guilds.cache.get;
    guild.members.forEach(member => {
      if (member.roles.has("Member")) {
        member.kick()
      }
    })
  }
})
```

the error says:

> Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: That error is telling you `guild.members` doesn't exist so you can't call `forEach` on it. Log `guild` and check what you actually have. `client.guilds.cache.get` is a more than likely a function you need to call

Comment: `.get` is a method. `guild` will therefor be a function. A function doesn't have a `members` property -> `undefined` -> https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=get

Answer (score 0):

`client.guilds.cache.get` is a function and must be called with `()`. Also, you must provide a guild ID as the first, and only parameter.

```
var guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD-ID")
```

Next, `GuildMemberManager`s have a [`cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache) property which you should run [`.each`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=each) on.

```
guild.members.cache.each(member => {
  if (member.roles.cache.has("ROLE-ID")) {
    member.kick()
  }
})
```

Comment: ty i will try now

Comment: it is saying this now: `member.roles.has is not a function`

Comment: Fixed that part too

Comment: If it works then you can mark this answer as correct

Comment: Ok i will check when i come home on like 5 hours thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on(`messageCreate`, async(message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${prefix}amstronglikeabullinapool`)) {
        message.channel.send(`ok i dont care`);
        let members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
        
        members.forEach((member) => {
            if (member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === `Member`)) {
                member.kick();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

There, fixed.